# Rewriterule htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am still new to .htaccess and I tried some sample RewriteRule which ends with a 500 internal server error.. I tried to check out some documentations out there, without having my answer. I want to change my url : www.mywebsite.com/products/apron/?item=B-200 to something like www.mywebsite.com/products/apron/B-200

So I created a .htaccess file with this in it :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^products/apron/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/$ /products/apron/?item=$1 [NC, L]
```

At the end, I just get a white page with a 500 internal server error.. I tried so many changes in my RewriteRule but always ended up with this error..

Answer (score 0):

Have it this way:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^products/apron/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/$ products/apron/?item=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

- No space before `L` flag to avoid 500 error.
- `Options -MultiViews` is used to avoid content negotiation conflicting with `mod_rewrite`